trying to use (WSL) bash -c to execute a command(export variable), but failed
on WSL, I am trying to use bash -c to execute a string as command:
bash -c "export MY_HOME=/mnt/d ; echo $MY_HOME"
but the result shows that $MY_HOME  is empty
I think it might be that the dollar sign is not recognized, but I dont know how to solve it. I appreciate if anyone could help me. Thank yoU!
enter image description here Here's what I tried in powershell

Maybe you could try:
bash -c 'export MY_HOME=/mnt/d ; echo $MY_HOME'

If you enter the command in the WSL instance, the command is interpreter by WSL shell (likely bash) and $MY_HOME is replaced by empty string before bash -c receive it.
After variable expansion from WSL shell, the command that is launched is:
bash -c "export MY_HOME=/mnt/d ; echo "


Thank you. but here's another question: I used C# code to generate this string command like this: string command = $"export MY_HOME={directory}; echo $MY_HOME", so is there a way that I can replace the double quote by single quote?
